# Bottle mysql connect

Tags: python, mysql, bottle

I am trying connect to mysql in bottle framework but with no success. Error tells me to give second argument to route but I do not want additional argument in url.

```
import bottle
import bottle_mysql
from bottle import route, run, template, app

app = bottle.Bottle()
plugin = bottle_mysql.Plugin(dbuser='root', dbpass='toor', dbname='database')
app.install(plugin)

@route('/show/<a>')
def show(a, db):
    db.execute('SELECT * FROM table WHERE a > "%d"', (a,))
    return template('Hello {{name}}, how are you?', name=a)

run(host='192.168.1.19', port=8080, debug=True)
```

Error:

```
TypeError('show() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)',)
```

Comment: Could it be that you need to use `@app.route` instead of  `@route`?

Comment: When I use @app.route such as in https://github.com/tg123/bottle-mysql I got 404

Comment: @MaartenBicknese is correct, it should be `@app.route`.  How did you call your server when you got a 404?

Comment: PS. I hope `toor` is not your actual root password.

Comment: @ ron.rothman I don't understand question. I call server the same as always.

Comment: That is working: http://pastebin.com/0r5f9J4K .
That is not working: http://pastebin.com/uHF1mnA8

Comment: you could also try `app.run` in the last line, together with `@app.route`

Comment: Also, if your table is really called `table`, you better be explicit about the name `\`table\`` in your SQL query

Answer (score 1):

You may want to create db as a global variable and remove it as a parameter for the function show() or possibly make it an optional variable

Answer (score 0):

The author of bottle-mysql says :

> to automatically detect routes that need a database connection, 
>   the plugin searches for route callbacks that require a *db* keyword 
>   argument (configurable) and skips routes that do not.

Each route needs to be configured as belonging to the app or the app's plugin can't send data via that route.
So you *do* need the "`app.`" in `@app.route('/show/<a>')`

And your run statement on the last line needs to specify the app too otherwise it won't recognise the routes belonging to the app.

`run(app, host='192.168.1.19', port=8080, debug=True)`

Answer (score 0):

As others have responded, you need to change:

```
@route('/show/<a>')
```

to:

```
@app.route('/show/<a>')
```

But this is not the only change you need to make to solve the issue, you also need to change:

```
run(host='192.168.1.19', port=8080, debug=True)
```

to:

```
app.run(host='192.168.1.19', port=8080, debug=True)
```

Unfortunately this last part is not clear in the documentation and took a bit of guess work to figure out, but it's actually pretty obvious actually because if you just call `run` without the `app.` prefix, you're basically running a new bottle instance, which will result in 404 errors tying to access your routes.